# Load image from byte array

Tags: c#, tesseract

I'm using tesseract to read string from images. I have a class containing images, width/height and matrix points (in a byte array, images are in grayscale).

I have a main image and I crop it into little images. Actually i'm saving all croped image in my disk but it take so many place.

Is there a way to process tesseract engine from a byte array?

There is my code:

```
class MyImage
{
    public String Name;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public Byte[] Matrix;

    public MyImage Crop(int x, int y, int w, int h);
    public void PrintToFile(String path);
}

String ReadImage(MyImage img, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    MyImage cropImg = img.Crop(x,y,w,h);
    String path = cropImg.Name;
    cropImg.PrintToFile(path);

    TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(".", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);

    String ExtractedText;
    using (Page page = engine.Process(new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path)))
    {
        ExtractedText = page.GetText();
    }

    return ExtractedText;
}
```

Comment: Load the byte array into a memory stream, then load the image from the stream? 
 `Image.FromStream(stream)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

[Image to Byte Array and Byte Array to Image Converter Class](http://Image%20to%20Byte%20Array%20and%20Byte%20Array%20to%20Image%20Converter%20Class)